# Pyomo (Transportation theory): Trying to show a variable with the sum of other variables

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm trying to solve the classical 'Transportation theory' to optimize the production and transportation of goods from 3 factories to 2 distribution centers, through 2 weeks.

There are:

3x2 max capacities in each factory (items/week)
3x2x2 transportation costs from each factory to each distribution center ($/item/week)
2x2 weekly demand volume in each distribution center (items/week)

I want to consider the value of the production of each factory (each week), and created the variable 'production' in the model.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()
model.T = Set(initialize=[1, 2]) #Weeks
model.i = Set(initialize=['Factory A','Factory B', 'Factory C'])
model.j = Set(initialize=['DC 1', 'DC 2'])
model.a = Param(model.T, model.i, initialize={\
    (1, 'Factory A'): 1000, (1, 'Factory B'): 1000, (1, 'Factory C'): 1000, \
    (2, 'Factory A'): 1000, (2, 'Factory B'): 1000, (2, 'Factory C'): 1000}) #Weekly_capacities
model.b = Param(model.T, model.j, initialize={(1, 'DC 1'): 500, (1, 'DC 2'): 501, \
    (2, 'DC 1'): 500, (2, 'DC 2'): 501}) #Weekly_demands

# Transportation costs
costs = {\
    (1, 'Factory A', 'DC 1'): 1000,(1, 'Factory B', 'DC 1'): 1001, (1, 'Factory C', 'DC 1'): 1002, \
    (1, 'Factory A', 'DC 2'): 2000,(1, 'Factory B', 'DC 2'): 2001, (1, 'Factory C', 'DC 2'): 2002, \
    (2, 'Factory A', 'DC 1'): 1000,(2, 'Factory B', 'DC 1'): 1001, (2, 'Factory C', 'DC 1'): 1002, \
    (2, 'Factory A', 'DC 2'): 2000,(2, 'Factory B', 'DC 2'): 2001, (2, 'Factory C', 'DC 2'): 2002}

model.d = Param(model.T, model.i, model.j, initialize=costs)

def f_costs(model, T, i, j):
    return model.d[T, i,j]
model.c = Param(model.T, model.i, model.j, initialize=f_costs)

model.x = Var(model.T, model.i, model.j, bounds=(0.0,None)) #Production

def f_supply(model, T, i):
    return sum(model.x[T,i,j] for j in model.j) <= model.a[T,i]
model.supply = Constraint(model.T, model.i, rule=f_supply)

def f_demand(model, T, j):
    return sum(model.x[T,i,j] for i in model.i) >= model.b[T,j]  
model.demand = Constraint(model.T, model.j, rule=f_demand)

model.production = Var(model.T, model.i, bounds=(0.0,None))
def production(model, T, i):    
    return sum(model.x[T,i,j] for j in model.j)

def f_objetive(model):
    return sum(model.c[T,i,j]*model.x[T,i,j] for T in model.T for i in model.i for j in model.j)
model.objetive = Objective(rule=f_objetive, sense=minimize)

opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
results = opt.solve(model)
model.x.display()
model.production.display()
```

This is the output

```
x : Size=12, Index=x_index
    Key                      : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    (1, 'Factory A', 'DC 1') :   0.0 : 500.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (1, 'Factory A', 'DC 2') :   0.0 : 500.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (1, 'Factory B', 'DC 1') :   0.0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (1, 'Factory B', 'DC 2') :   0.0 :   1.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (1, 'Factory C', 'DC 1') :   0.0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (1, 'Factory C', 'DC 2') :   0.0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory A', 'DC 1') :   0.0 : 500.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory A', 'DC 2') :   0.0 : 500.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory B', 'DC 1') :   0.0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory B', 'DC 2') :   0.0 :   1.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory C', 'DC 1') :   0.0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory C', 'DC 2') :   0.0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False :  Reals
production : Size=6, Index=production_index
    Key              : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    (1, 'Factory A') :   0.0 :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
    (1, 'Factory B') :   0.0 :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
    (1, 'Factory C') :   0.0 :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory A') :   0.0 :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory B') :   0.0 :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
    (2, 'Factory C') :   0.0 :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
```

I expected that the 'production' variable would show the sum up of the 'x' of each factory for each DC. This is: 1000, 1, 0, 1000, 1, 0.

However, the 'production' variable shows empty values. I'm sure I'm not understanding the sense of the Pyomo variables.

I've tried to use the constraint 'supply' within the objetive, since 'supply' show the desired value of the production of each factory, but I get the following error message:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and '_GeneralConstraintData'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `model.production` variable appears to be just a convenience to get weekly totals as it is not relevant in the model.  There are better ways to get the data out, but let's figure out why it is empty...

The `model.production` data is not associated with the `production` function.  It isn't clear what you were trying to do there.  Initializing that way will not work as no values are known at initialization.  Your only option to make it work would be to implement an equality constraint to tie it to the sum over weeks as such:

```
model.production = Var(model.T, model.i, bounds=(0.0,None))
def production(model, T, i):    
    return model.production[T, i] == sum(model.x[T,i,j] for j in model.j)
model.production_tie = Constraint(model.T, model.i, rule=production)
```

Realize this is just bloat in your model though and you should probably just compute the totals from the result as such:

```
production = {(week, factory) : sum(model.x[week, factory, destination].value for destination in model.j)
              for week in model.T
              for factory in model.i}
```

A few other nits...

- be sure you check the results for solver status.  I don't see that you are printing or inspecting it
- consider being more consistent with your sets, one is caps, others are not.
- `model.c` == `model.d` right now